# Does SignalR for a blazor server run in background and where

Tags: blazor

I have this statement :

> A Blazor Server app is built on top of ASP.NET Core SignalR. UI updates, event handling, and JavaScript calls are handled over a SignalR connection. This statement implies SignalR is operates in the background. The examples from MS though have a sample app that loads a nuget package and uses SignalR Hub.  In my simple blazor server app rest services are called by way of service class. In a run of the mill asp.Net razor page a POST back would get a new page. Under the default template for Blazor server app has a data folder and a service that is registered in program.cs

Does the registering the service hide the invocation of signalR to get data? And the SignalR invoked by that service in the background?

Comment: _"... implies SignalR is operates in the background"_ - Not rerally. There is no foreground or background in an asp.net app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blazor Server is a bit confusing!

The SignalR connection in Blazor Server is between the Blazor Server JS code running in the Browser and the Hub Session running on the server.

This line starts it in *_Host.cshtml*

```html
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

The SignalR session is used to pass DOM updates and JSInterop calls between the hub session and the browser and browser generated events between the browser and the hub session.

This line in `Program` adds the server middleware to intercept and run the Hub sessions.

```cs
app.MapBlazorHub();
```

In Blazor Server, ALL C# code runs on the server, JS code runs on the Browser.

In a Blazor Server application, the API calls are made from the server: there's no SignalR involved in the Server to API provider connection.  You configure the HttpClient service and then inject it into whatever service you're coding that needs it.  You should consider using the HttpClient Factory to ensure efficient use of HttpClient resources - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory.

Where services are run depends on their scope.  Singleton services are run in the main application Services container.  Scoped and Transient services are run the the Hub session service container.  There's one per SPA session.

Here's a quick guide to a typical operation:

1. You click a button in the browser to get some data.
2. The UI event is captured by the browser Blazor JS code and  transmitted by SignalR back to the hub session.
3. The Renderer in the hub session ties the event into a C# event handler method in a component in the current "page" and invokes it.  The method executes in the context of it's class instance using resources such as injected services.
4. If that's an API call though a DI registered data broker then it makes the call, gets the data and returns it to the caller.
5. The event triggers a component tree render which updates the handler owning component and any sub-components.  This updates the Renderer's DOM.
6. The Renderer's diffing engine detects any DOM changes and transits them over the SignalR session to the browser side Blazor JS code which  applies them to the browser DOM.
7. The screen updates showing the requested data.

Comment: Thanks this makes so much more sense !!! Im using VS 2022 17.5  the _Host.cshtml doesn't contain the script ref but _Layout.cshtml does have it and now I see MapBlazorHub() near end of program,cs

Comment: Yes, MS have messed a bit with _Host and _Layout.  Net6.0 they decided to separate things out, and then in Net7.0 decided that wasn't such a good idea!

Comment: There is state ambiguity in the statement "the API calls are made from the server: there's no SignalR involved." I would add at the end of that sentence "...involved at that point of the process".

Comment: @ΩmegaMan. Updated that sentence as I agree with you.